# What is the reasoning behind the definition of Shannon Entropy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

Shannon entropy is defined as the average content of information. Where information content is defined as $Q=-k\log(P_i)$, $k>0$,

$$
S = \langle Q \rangle = \sum_{i=1} Q_i P_i = -k\sum_{i=1} P_i\log(P_i) 
$$

That being said, my question is why $\langle Q\rangle = \sum_{i=1} Q_i P_i  $? More specifically, why is the information content multiplied by the probability of that information content itself? If there are any resources that you also suggestion, I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Shannon talks quite a lot about the reasoning behind his information measure in the original paper on the topic [Shannon 1948 A mathematical theory of communication](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6773024).

Answer (score 1):

The angle brackets around $Q$ mean that we are taking the *expected value* of the $Q$ distribution. For a random variable $X$ with probability distribution $\{P_i\equiv P(X_i)\}$, the definition of expected value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) is:

$$\langle X\rangle=\sum_i X_iP(X_i)=\sum_iX_iP_i$$

Comment: I see. I guess I am mainly more curious about why the content information is multiplied by the probability. This idea of state mutliplied by its probability is also deeply rooted in quantum mechanics as well. Do we do this multiplication due to taking the average of the content?

Comment: This is how you take expectation values: you multiply the value by its probability, and sum over all possible values.

Comment: @bapowell thank you, this is what I was looking for!